# Insert text before each item in __VA_ARGS__ in macro in c++ or c

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is there a simple way to do something with each argument in a variadic macro? I need to insert a macro before each item.

For example

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
   #define OTHER_MACRO int
   #define INSERT_STUFF(...) 
  
   INSERT_STUFF(v1, v2);
   // Expected output:
   // int v1; // From OTHER_MACRO v1
   // int v2; // From OTHER_MACRO v2
  
   // Possible other form, I would prefer if this was possible
   #define INSERT_STUFF2(PREFX, ...)
  
  
   INSERT_STUFF(OTHER_MACRO, v1, v2);
   // Expected output:
   // int v1;
   // int v2;
}
```

The example with using int is just a simplified example, what I'm after is how to do something to each item in a variadic macro arguments.

Question is tagged as c++/c because I expect the preprocessor to work in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use boost preprocessing

---

the basic form

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define OTHER_MACRO(i,d,x) int x;
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(OTHER_MACRO, , (a)(b)(c) )
```

---

specialize to what you want

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define DECLARE_VARIABLE(i,F,x) F x;
#define INSERT_STUFF(F, ...) \
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_VARIABLE, F, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

INSERT_STUFF(int,x,y,z)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PdnajnvK3

Comment: I'm generally against including boost for doing small stuff, but to be honest this is the cleanest version I have seen so It might as well be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is not actually to insert text before each item in an argument list; that is only a hypothetical solution you thought of. Your actual goal is to do multiple things with a list of items, for which we can use a [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). To do this, we define a macro that applies some argument (or hard-coded macro name) to a list of items. Then we invoke that macro with whatever macro we would like applied to the list (or, when using a hard-coded macro name, we change the definition of that macro name before using the list macro). Here is an example:

```
#define ApplyToList(X)  X(v1) X(v2) X(v3)

#define DeclareAsInt(Name)  int Name;
#define Print(Name) printf(#Name " is %d.\n", Name);


#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    ApplyToList(DeclareAsInt)

    v1 = 11;
    v2 = 22;
    v3 = 33;

    ApplyToList(Print)
}
```

The source code inside `main` is replaced with:

```
 int v1; int v2; int v3;

 v1 = 11;
 v2 = 22;
 v3 = 33;

 printf("v1" " is %d.\n", v1); printf("v2" " is %d.\n", v2); printf("v3" " is %d.\n", v3);
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it work variadically, though? Because I'm pretty sure OP specifically wants not to have to hard-code the count of variables in `ApplyToList`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: There is no hard-coded count.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the `v1 v2 v3` are not `__VA_ARGS__` and is hard coded.

Comment: @appleapple: Yes, the list is hard-coded in the macro. It may be any length. There is no hard-coded count. One may redefine the macro or define alternate macros with other lists.

Comment: @EricPostpischil wait, I think I get it now. So you redefine the lists before using the macro... A bit contraintuivive but I might actually have a go with this if the boost stuff does not fit my application